# How to analyze simple English sentences

Tags: java, nlp

Is there any library that can be used for analyzing (nlp) simple english text. For example it would be perfect if it can do that;
Input: "I am going"
Output: I, go, present continuous tense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about the [Natural Language Toolkit](http://www.nltk.org/)?

Answer (score 2):

Try StanFord's NLP stuff [here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/index.shtml).

Answer (score 2):

Part of speech is often useful in Text-to-Speech engines.  Part of the process of determining the pronunciation requires knowing the part of speech:

> The lead pipe led the detective to the lead in the play.

I know there are several parsers available as part of the [Festival Project](http://www.cstr.ed.ac.uk/projects/festival/). This [article](http://www.vinartus.net/spa/95a.pdf) may provide some insight into the techniques used.  English is very mild in comparison to some of the other languages so be prepared to struggle.

Answer (score 1):

I find the [Link Grammar](http://www.link.cs.cmu.edu/link/) very interesting. Check it out!