# Processing English Statements

Tags: nlp

Any recommendations for languages/libraries to convert sentence like:

> "X bumped Y, who in turn kicked Z."

to

1. X: Bumped
2. Y: Was bumped, kicked Z

Comment: X: Was bumped should say X: bumped

Comment: I have no idea about nlp, but X was not bumped in the sentence? It bumped Y.

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest you use the Stanford Parser (http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml), which is open source and relatively simple, as these things go.  With it, you can extract a typed dependency parse.  A dependency parse of a sentence basically decomposes a sentence into a set of binary relations `r(B, A)`, where word A grammatically depends on word B.

Take your sentence

X bumped Y, who in turn kicked Z.

In this sentence, both X and Y depend on bumped to get their grammatical relationship in this sentence.  The Stanford Parser would extract the following relations for them:

```
nsubj(bumped, X)
dobj(bumped, Y)
```

This means the subject of bumped is X and the direct object of bumped is Y.  You could then use this information to make a grammatical relation: `bumped(X, Y)`.  Likewise, the Stanford Parser extracts the following relations for the rest of the sentence:

```
nsubj(kicked, who)
rcmod(Y, kicked)
dobj(kicked, Z)
```

In this case, you have the subject of kicked being "who", with Y as the `rcmod` (relative clause modifier).  I'm not sure what the goal of your system is, but you would probably find that you need to construct a bunch of rules manually to cover situations.  In this case, your rule could equate the `rcmod` with the `nsubj` in order to produce `kicked(Y, Z)`.

For more information on using the Stanford Parser typed dependencies, there is an excellent tutorial on the subject at the Stanford Parser website (http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/dependencies_manual.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

To blatantly rip off [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/745334/how-to-analyze-simple-english-sentences/745353#745353), why not try the [Natural Language Toolkit](http://www.nltk.org/)?

Answer (score 1):

The Stanford Parser as suggested by ealdent would do the job, I would prefer to encode it as:

- Bump(X,Y,Past)
- Kick(Y,Z,Past)

A POS tagger could also work, but your sentence is complicated ("who in turn").

Comment: Annotating the relation to reflect tense would be good, I was just giving an example.  You might want to add other annotations (like index in sentence, part of speech), as well.

A POS tagger would give you the POS tags in order, but you'd have to come up with rules determining whether something is a direct object or a subject, and that will quickly get too complicated unless you're a syntactic rules junkie.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the Stanford parser, [RASP](http://www.informatics.sussex.ac.uk/research/groups/nlp/rasp/) is a possibility too - it can produce lists of grammatical relations as part of its output.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318197/how-to-determine-subject-object-and-other-words).

Answer (score 0):

A multilingual commercial alternative: [GlobalNLP](https://nlp.linguasys.com/docs/services/53fccbb15cfea30d9c48f8d6/operations/542a6da01c78d80a3cd6692a)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are interested in identifying the semantic roles in the sentence. SRL tools tag the entities with their corresponding roles. You can play with the [demo](http://barbar.cs.lth.se:8081/parse) of one of the tools.

In the relation *bumped*, X is tagged as A0 (agent) and Y is tagged as A1 (patient).